# Save Magento 1.9.2 contact form data in database?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, contact-us

I want to store Magento 1.9.2 contact form data into database?
I have create a New DB Table and create new Module on local Pool but Controller overwrite is not working.

I want to send email as well store all the data in my custom table.

## My Code Is:

/app/etc/modules/Codefire_Contacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codefire_Contacts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Codefire_Contacts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Codefire/Contacts/controllers/indexController.php

```
<?php

require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php');

class Codefire_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController {

    //your targeted controller action rewrite here
    public function indexAction() {
        parent::indexAction();
        echo 'Good';
        die;
    }

    public function postAction() {
        echo 'Good';
        die;
    }

}
```

/app/code/local/Codefire/Contacts/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codefire_Contacts>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Codefire_Contacts>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Codefire_Contacts before="Mage_Contacts">Codefire_Contacts</Codefire_Contacts>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Its not working...

Answer (score 2):

Make change in following file

**/app/etc/modules/Codefire_Contacts.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codefire_Contacts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool> <!--If your extension is in community codePool then use community-->
        </Codefire_Contacts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Change your controller file name from **indexController.php** to **IndexController.php**. **i** should be in upppercase.

Comment: Its my mistake during copy paste the code.. but its not working

Comment: Disable your cache and compilation from admin

Comment: Thanks i have already do this.. But its OS issue.. working fine.. Thanks yr time

Answer (score 2):

Please add the following code in the config.xml file.

```
 <global>
    <rewrite>
        <customcontactus>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/contacts/index/#]]></from>
            <to>/contactform/index/</to>
        </customcontactus>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

Rewrite the postAction() controller file and add the following code.

```
$model = Mage::getModel("contactform/contactformsave");
            $model->setData(array('created_at'=>NOW(),'name'=>$post['name'],
                'email'=>$post['email'],'telephone'=>$post['telephone'],
                'comment'=>$post['comment']));
            $model->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->
                    __('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

Please refer my tutorial for full code and file structure.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/save-contact-form-data-magento-database/

Answer (score 1):

If create a module then you must need define it *`codePool`* at module config file and without it **cannot be possible to run the extension**.There `are 3 type of codePool local,community,core`.
***`Codefire_Contacts.xml`***

You did not define it.So as per as,Rohit Kundale  said ,you should be define codePool.

**Basic format of module config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool> <!-- it value may be local,core,community -->
        </ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Its my mistake during copy paste the code.. but its not working

Comment: change `require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php');` to  `require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php';`

Comment: No! But its OS issue.. working fine.. Thanks yr time

Comment: make `indexController.php` to `IndexController.php`.*`i`*should be  uppercas